# How to run fetch before export variable in JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Like above , i want to export array which contains some data from api but here a thing , export before run fetch so array empty for exporting . I tried timeout for export but not working . So how can i do it ? 
Thank you !
This is my code :

```
  const arr = [];
     fetch(base, {
     method: 'GET',
     headers: {
         'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
  })
   .then(response => { response.json()}).then(json => {
  arr.push(json);
 })


export default arr // show empty
```

Finally, i got it by my way , so i explain for someone who were sticking as same as me .
Here is that , export function return promise and use that promise callback inside function and push on any array we need to do from import promise .

Comment: `Const` should be `const`. Can you try wrapping as a function such as `getArray` and exporting the function?

Comment: Yup, i had tried but they didn't , when we return and export by Class , Those code couldn't be figured out when exported and another file imported to use .

Comment: Please read this before using fetch. https://blog.hospodarets.com/fetch_in_action

Comment: what the hell are you trying to do ? expose a variable from an exposed module from a get request ? o_O ?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38465919/node-js-es6-module-export-async-variable

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the return keyword before response.json(). I think what's happening is that your first .then isn't returning a promise*, which means the second .then is receiving undefined as the json argument.

*see comment below; it *is* returning a promise, but it resolves to undefined

Comment: `then` Always return a promise. That promise can be resolved with `undefined`? Yes. https://promisesaplus.com/#point-40

Comment: Thanks for answering , Those worked when i set timeout and console.log this array . Otherwise , i try to export in promise , but err not working

Comment: Good call, Jamie, yes it is a promise that resolves to undefined!

Comment: @NhatHoangVy There is not way for you to know when the response was pushed to the array. You should export the function that return a promise instead of the array (or something similar).

Comment: @NhatHoangVy Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38465919/node-js-es6-module-export-async-variable

Comment: Yup, i tried , but it didn't work when i import it into state for another function whose used for state (Redux) . You know what i meant

Comment: @Jaime i got it . Thanks for advise, sir